# Christian hangmen in Islamic countries?

Tags: religion, islam, christianity, pakistan, death-penalty

In an [interview](http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/latenightlive/pakistan3a-who27s-in-charge3f/6083520) a senior researcher at Amnesty International explained that

> as far as I know certainly in Punjab and Sind provinces, the two
>   largest provinces by population, the hangmen [executioners] are
>   Christians.

Do we know if this (if true in the first place) is a coincidence, or specific to modern Pakistan, or if there is perhaps a wider pattern that history can explain by clear evidence? Notice that Pakistan has a Christian population of [1.6 %](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan) in 196 million.

Comment: Perhaps because they belong to the same family? See [this](http://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2011/01/05/city/lahore/confessions-of-an-executioner/) about the Masih family. Also [this](http://tribune.com.pk/story/223212/kot-lakhpat-jail-the-hangman/).

Comment: @Rajib So a coincident then?

Comment: I would think so. While the percentage of Christians is low, you realize that percentage of Hangmen is even lower. Also, in India for instance, its increasingly difficult to find hangmen. See [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1393163/Hangman-wanted-Indian-state-searches-executioner-carry-death-sentence-years.html) for instance, and also [this](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/death-for-kasab-but-where-is-the-hangman/article423387.ece).

Comment: How is this a historical question?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude It is asking whether there is a related historic pattern or not. (Rest assured it is not meant to offend any religions.)

Comment: In Pakistan it is usual specially for civil servants to make sure that their sons  (Or at least one son) follows the father's position in administration. Some departments often offer place of retired/dead distinguished civil servants to their sons as recognition of the father's service especially in Police Department.